# Automating capture network traffic through browser mob proxy in Appium

Tags: appium, browsermob-proxy

I am having trouble getting Browsermob proxy to capture network traffic.

I am using Appium to write tests in android app. I want to use Browser mob proxy to capture and verify network calls. Browser mob proxy is being started at port 19536. I am using a shell script to turn Mac proxy on at port 19536.

Below is the code I am using but I can't see any network requests in the HAR file. Its pretty much empty.

Can someone help? TIA.

Code

```
  //Start Proxy Server
  server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
  server.start(19536);

  //Turn Mac http Proxy on
  Global.runShellCmdWithArg("/usr/local/bin/webproxy.sh", "on");

  // get the Selenium proxy object
  Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(server);

  File appDir = new File("/build/outputs/apk/");
  File app = new File(appDir, "Demo-debug.apk");

  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
  capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
  capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.test");
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);

  driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
  server.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.REQUEST_BINARY_CONTENT);
  server.newHar("newHar");

  testApp = new DemoAppPage(driver);
  wait =  new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

  testApp.clickGetStarted(); 
  testApp.clickButton();

  // Get the HAR data
  Har har = server.getHar();
  File harFile = new File("test.har");
  har.writeTo(harFile);
```

Comment: Can any one help?

Comment: Any luck with it? Even i am stuck with the same!